# Javascript Regex Replace something://something.something with something else

Tags: javascript, regex

I didn't really know what to title this but I'm trying my best.

So I'm coding some Javascript right now and I'm trying to detect/replace something

for example, i want `uii://thiscanbeanything.eau` to be changed to `epp://t.e`,etc

it will always begin with `ui` but it can be `uii` or `uie`/`uiq`, and it will always end with `.e` but it can be `.eq`/`.ep`/`.eyqk`, etc

I know how to replace it but I'm just trying to get the correct Regex for it

I tried `/ui.*:\/\/.*\.e.*/igm` but it does it to the whole line, I just want it to replace the one parse.

So basically I want it to Replace it just like how I did but I want it to only do it to one Parse without ANY Spaces, for example, i know how to do it to stuff like `abc.stuff.xyz` to make it `abc.somethingelse.xyz`, etc but with this, it replaces the whole string instead of just one word.

I'm new to Regex so don't be surprised if I missed something that's really obvious or easy. when replying it would be great if you were to explain how it works

Comment: `it does it to the whole line` > what's the whole line? Alternatively, is the part after the dot of known length?

Comment: you are being too generic in your question, we cannot really help you for a regex to change "anything" into anything, or i'd answer use `/.*/` to replace all that.. You should be more precise on the result you expect, if it is `epp://t.e` everytime, no use to elaborate a regex. By the way, for the general way to do it, you can use round brackets to isolate the parts you want to replace, in your case something like `/(ui.*):\/\/(.*)\.(e.*)/igm`

Comment: @Kaddath believe it or not; you solved my question.

Comment: lol, life can be simple sometimes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to replace a text without spaces within a text, it makes sence to use word-boundaries `\b`, and `\S` to match anything that's not a whitespace.

And being specific, like looking for letters `[a-z]*` instead of using `.*` makes it more clear to regex what you need.

Example:

```js
var str = "blah uii://thiscanbeanything.eau blah";

const regex = /\b(ui[a-z]?):\/\/(\S*)\.(e[a-z]{0,3})\b/gi;

console.log(str.replace(regex, "epp://t.e"));

// using the capture groups
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1://something.$3"));
```

The `m` multiline flag isn't used, because the regex isn't using `^` & `$` for the start & end of the line.